# How to handle exception, so the script continues to work?

Tags: python, exception

There is a script which makes API requests through iterating of a params dictionary.

If params are not compatible between each other (metrics and dimensions) or there is a mistake, it throws an exception:

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: "Could not parse content (N/A) of field parameters.filters.">

And the script stops working.

It looks like this

```
def yt_return_api_response(yt_params):
    responses = []
    timestamp = []

    try:
        youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
        for k, v in yt_params.items():
            request = execute_api_request(
                youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
                ids=v['ids'],
                startDate=v['startDate'],
                endDate=v['endDate'],
                metrics=v['metrics'],
                dimensions=v['dimensions'],
                filters=v['filters'],
                maxResults=v['maxResults'],
                sort=v['sort'])
            response = youtube_response(request)
            responses.append(response)

            # get the timestamp
            timestamp_request = dt.datetime.now()
            timestamp_request = timestamp_request.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            timestamp.append(timestamp_request)

       return responses, timestamp

except Exception as e:
        logging.error('Check the request params, unsupported query', exc_info=True)
```

I've tried to change it, in order after one iteration if there is a mistake it would not crash but continues to work.

With 'while True' it starts and just keeps working without any result.

```
def yt_return_api_response(yt_params, request_ids, filters):
    responses = []
    timestamp = []
    while True:
               try:
```

with 'finally' returns empty lists

```
def yt_return_api_response(yt_params):
    responses = []
    timestamp = []
    try:
        youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
        for k, v in yt_params.items():
            request = execute_api_request(
                youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
                ids=v['ids'],
                startDate=v['startDate'],
                endDate=v['endDate'],
                metrics=v['metrics'],
                dimensions=v['dimensions'],
                filters=v['filters'],
                maxResults=v['maxResults'],
                sort=v['sort'])
            response = youtube_response(request)
            responses.append(response)

            # get the timestamp
            timestamp_request = dt.datetime.now()
            timestamp_request = timestamp_request.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            timestamp.append(timestamp_request)

    except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Check the request params, unsupported query', exc_info=True)

   finally:
          return responses, timestamp
```

Is there other way to handle exceptions?

Comment: It looks like you're talking about 2 problems. You want to ignore a raised exception or you do not understand why your code returns an empty list? And please, specify also which line throws the error, maybe with the full traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to skip one itteration, your code when catch exception go out from loop. You can try to skip one iteration like that:

```
def yt_return_api_response(yt_params):
    responses = []
    timestamp = []
    youtubeAnalytics = get_service()
    for k, v in yt_params.items():
        try:
            request = execute_api_request(
                youtubeAnalytics.reports().query,
                ids=v['ids'],
                startDate=v['startDate'],
                endDate=v['endDate'],
                metrics=v['metrics'],
                dimensions=v['dimensions'],
                filters=v['filters'],
                maxResults=v['maxResults'],
                sort=v['sort'])
            response = youtube_response(request)
            responses.append(response)

            # get the timestamp
            timestamp_request = dt.datetime.now()
            timestamp_request = timestamp_request.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            timestamp.append(timestamp_request)
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Check the request params, unsupported query', exc_info=True)

    return responses, timestamp
```